# relaciones many to many en laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Estoy hacinedo una pagina que va a mostrar los productos que venden los locales de un centro comercial, estos productos los tengo que dividir por categorias, para esto utilízo una tabla transaccional para hacer las relaciones, no conozco muy bien laravel.
Ese es el código que tengo en el controlador

```
 $products = Product::all();
 $categories = Department::all();
 $categories_products = DepartentProduct::all();
 return view('products/index', ['products'=>$products, 
                                'categories'=>$categories, 
                                'cps'=>$categories_products]);
```

y en la vista hago lo siguiente

```
@foreach($categories as $categorie)
    <div class="sponsor-section padding-bottom">
        <div class="container">
            <h3>{{$categorie->name}}</h3>
            <div class="sponsor-slider">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    @foreach( $cps as $cp )
                        @foreach($products as $product)
                            @if($product->id == $cp->product_id && $categorie->id == $cp->department_id)
                                <div class="swiper-slide">
                                    <div class="sponsor-thumb">
                                        <a href="products/{{$product->slug}}"><img src="{{asset('storage/'.$product->image)}}" alt="sponsor"></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Entiendo que esta no es la forma mas óptima de todas para realizar lo que quiero

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las ultimas 2 categorías solo tienen 1 producto pero por la iteración lo repíte la misma cantidad de veces que el número de categorias.
Quisiera sabercomo puedo hacer esto de manera mas óptima

Comment: Creatse las respectivas relaciones de Eloquent en cada modelo?

Comment: Si cree esta relación, no se si esta del todo bien 
public function department(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Department', 'departent_products')->withPivot('department_id');
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considera que si estás trabajando una relación de *Muchos a Muchos*, tus modelos `Product` y `Category` deberían tener las siguientes declaraciones:

Modelo Product

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class);
}
```

Modelo Category

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

Ahora para construir la consulta, evita cargar cada selección de los registros asociados a tus entidades por separado, considera usar [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) y con eso no pasarás por el problema de *N + 1*

El caso de tu consulta pudiera ser de este modo

**Opción 1**

```
$categories = Category::with('products')->get();
```

Con la anterior consulta vas a obtener todos los productos agrupados en la categoría con la cual fueron dados de alta **pudiendo aparecer mas de un producto a la vez pues puede estar dado de alta en mas de una categoría**

Si opcionalmente deseas obtener todos los productos de una determinada categoría lo puedes hacer de este modo:

**Opción 2**

```
$categories = Category::with('products')->findOrFail($id);
```

El método `findOrFail` buscará filtrar por medio del id de la entidad, en este caso `Category`

Por ejemplo desde *Tinker* la posible salida se vería algo como esto:

```
>>> App\Category::with('products')->find(1);
=> App\Category {#3017
     id: 1,
     title: "categoria titulo",
     created_at: "2020-01-01 21:58:27",
     updated_at: "2020-01-01 21:58:27",
     products: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3025
       all: [
         App\Product {#3030
           id: 1,
           name: "producto uno",
           created_at: "2020-01-01 21:57:39",
           updated_at: "2020-01-01 21:57:39",
           pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#3023
             category_id: 1,
             product_id: 1,
           },
         },
         App\Product {#3027
           id: 3,
           name: "producto tres",
           created_at: "2020-01-01 21:57:39",
           updated_at: "2020-01-01 21:57:39",
           pivot: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot {#3022
             category_id: 1,
             product_id: 3,
           },
         },
       ],
     },
   }
>>>
```

En cuanto a aspectos de convenciones de nombres, son importantes pues Eloquent de forma predeterminada buscará un patrón a cumplir con los nombres, para este punto te sugiero leas a detalle el enlace a la doc. oficial donde se explica que hacer si los nombres de columnas y/o tablas son distintos.

**Referencia**

- [Many to Many Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)